# Which episode in the Alabasta arc has Luffy ate all the food on the boat and Sanji ask him about it?

Tags: one-piece

In the Alabasta arc, there is an episode where Luffy eats all the food on the boat. When confronted by Sanji, Luffy responds with the following, all while whipping his hand back and forth:

> I really don't know what you're talking about.

Does anyone know what episode this is from?

[image: Luffy says "I really don't know what you're talking about" while whipping his hand back and forth]

Comment: I'm assuming that this happened early on in that arc because of them being on the boat still. Does that sound about right? Was Mr.2 still around?

Comment: Yupe and they have no idea about the top agents yet.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's from episode 92, titled "The Hero of Alabasta and the Ballerina on Deck".

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Mangfa. please do not pad out answers just to meet the minimum character requirement, it's there for a reason and if you're answer can't meet it then it's not enough to be a good answer

Comment: To be fair, I don't see what else this answer needs.

Comment: @senshin maybe an episode summary or a short description of the events that lead to the asked scene.